# php calculation works with html, not in email

Tags: php, math, echo

I got the following problem.

In the confermation email I sent from a store (Virtuemart platform) I would like to do an extra calculation.

See underneath script for 2 examples. Somehow the string of $order_total doesn't work for the confirmation emails...as the HTML order review does show the right calculation.

This works okay:

```
<?php $less_costs = "5";
$order_total = "15";
$endtotal = abs(floor($order_total) - $less_costs);
echo $endtotal ?><!-- output = 10 --!>
```

This doesn''t work in the email ( in HTML it is rendered okay)

```
<?php $less_costs = "5";
 $endtotal = abs(floor($order_total) - $less_costs);// $order_total is dynamic from the VM store
echo $endtotal ?><!-- output = 5 --!>
```

**---- EDIT ----**

I know it is not the easiest question, as it is not so for explaining it too ;), But I truly hope one of you could help me somehow.

[See this example](http://code.google.com/p/joosmart/source/browse/trunk/install_pack/components/com_virtuemart/themes/default/templates/order_emails/confirmation_email.tpl.php?spec=svn157&r=157) of the confirmation_email.tpl.php which sends the email with the order total. I've put the code above also in this php file (with the right string callings)

[See this example](http://www.codes-libres.org/apps/VirtueMart_1.1.2_eCommerce_Bundle_Joomla_1.5.9/nav.html?administrator/components/com_virtuemart/classes/ps_checkout.php.source.html) of the ps_checkout.php which renders all the prices in question.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean exactly? What do you get? What does the HTML look like?

Comment: So where are you setting $order_total for your email, because I'm guessing you're not

Comment: If I print the $endtotal in HTML (the online version of the order information) it shows the right amount. But in the email confirmation the output remains '5' instead of the calculated '10'

Comment: Where does `$order_total` come from? Have you checked its value? Because the problem is most likely there

Comment: @Sailes - You've already told us that in the question... now answer where the value of $order_total actually comes from when you send the email... if $order_total isn't set, or is 0, or is 10, then it will display 5 rather than 10

Comment: If `$order_total` is 10, it will *always* print 5.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server side language, a mail server cannot intepret PHP code. The email content has to be parsed server side, then the resultant HTML sent in the email.

Comment: I ve found the problem:

Their was an EURO sign before the price in the string. So I fixed it as followed:

    <?php $less_costs= '5.00';
    $order_total = str_replace("&euro;","",$order_total);
    $total = abs($order_total - $less_costs);  echo $totalrr ?>

Thanx for trying to help me anyways.